# "Unknown Protocol" Bonsai Elasticsearch on production Heroku (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku

I've got a rails 5 app deployed to heroku and I'm using the Bonsai Elasticsearch plugin. I've got it configured so it is indexing and searching properly from localhost, but failing in production

I have the following gems installed per the instructions [here](https://github.com/omc/bonsai-elasticsearch-rails) for v6.x:

```
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '~> 6'
gem 'elasticsearch-model', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: '6.x'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: '6.x'
```

When attemping to search or create an index I get the following error only in prod:

> Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol)

Also probably worth noting I'm using the sandbox version of Bonsai and a paid heroku dyno with autoconfigured SSL.

Comment: Hello, I am also having this issue and it seems to be pervasive beyond Bonsai. Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: What `elasticsearch` gem version are you using? Paste it from Gemfile.lock.

Comment: @davepaola yes, I reached out to Bonsai and they suggested adding :443 to end on the cluster URL.... see my answer below with more details

Comment: @phauwn thank you. I switched to a different provider and used a newer version. Fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with Bonsai support and they offered the following information which resolved my issue:

> Thanks for reaching out. The problem may be due to a breaking change Elastic introduced into the Ruby client (see the discussion [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/669)). Elastic has indicated that they're not planning to fix it.
>
> The simple fix is to append :443 to the end of your cluster URL. In other words, something like this:
>
> https://*:*@*.eu-west-1.bonsaisearch.net:443

Basically, they switched the default port from 443 to 9200 which broke many existing apps.